# How to configure VmWare to allow hosted machine to use static IP?

Tags: vmware, ip

There are two machines:

1. Windows Server
2. Windows 7

In order to install Domain Controller the machine has to have static IP because Domain Controller suppose to be DNS server.

How to configure VmWare to enable use of static ip for first machine while making possible to allocate dynamic ip for second machine (so they belong to the same LAN)?

DHCP for NAT configured to start form 128 to 254. When trying to assign 19.168.67.100 to guest it fails.

[image]

Comment: Can't you just use bridge mode then just manually set static IP in windows server?

Comment: Just assigned address which is not in the range of DHCP addresses and it worked